# How to make page error404?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Please help advice.

UsersController:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show]

  ........
  .........

  def show
    ......
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
      render_404 unless @user
    end
end
```

ApplicattionController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_locale

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  private

    def render_404
       render file: "public/404.html", status: 404
    end  
end
```

at `http://localhost:3000/users/24/` I see a page the user.

at `http://localhost:3000/users/24242424/` I see a page the error404.

at `http://localhost:3000/qwertyghjfd` I see a error message:

> Routing Error No route matches [GET]

I need to at `http://localhost:3000/qwertyghjfd` I saw a page error404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in ApplicationController you could call your render_404 when there is a routing error

`rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => : render_404`

Answer (score 0):

From the [official Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-default-500-and-404-templates):

> By default a production application will render either a 404 or a 500 error message. These messages are contained in static HTML files in the public folder, in 404.html and 500.html respectively.

The 404.html file is rendered (by default) in response to Routing errors in your *production* environment. In development you should see the actual error message (unless, of course, you override the default behaviour - the guides will tell you how).